# Obtaining Ipad touchstart coordinates

Tags: javascript, ipad, web-applications, touch, coordinates

I would like to obtain the coordinates of a touch event on the ipad in javascript. How would I do this?

Answer (score 6):

I believe this ought to do the trick:

```
var x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX,
    y = event.targetTouches[0].pageY;
```

**Update:** 
Here is an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Touch event test</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var $log = $("#log");

        function updateLog(x, y) {
            $log.html('X: '+x+'; Y: '+y);
        }

        document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
            updateLog(e.changedTouches[0].pageX, e.changedTouches[0].pageY);
        }, false);

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            updateLog(e.targetTouches[0].pageX, e.targetTouches[0].pageY);
        }, false);
    });
</script>

<div id="log"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We get an undefined value for event.targetTouches. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Tried the code in it's own file, works well, but when used in conjunction with our existing code, the line of script meant to generate an alert with the coordinates of the touch (used as a test before we actually implement it) does not work. Here's what we have:     `alert(event.changedTouches[0].pageX);`

Comment: If it doesn't generate an alert, then perhaps there is a bug in the implementation. Debugging it is out-of-scope of this question, so if you need help, post a new question and comment the link here.  I'll do my best to help out.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
x = event.originalEvent.pageX;
y = event.originalEvent.pageY;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but there is no accepted answer and the solution in my case with the iPad was below:

```
var x = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
var y = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
```