# Android 4.x - e.preventDefault e.pageX & e.pageY coordinates NON-JQUERY

Tags: javascript, cordova, touch

As the title says, I am running Android 4.x with PhoneGap.

I am not willing to use jQuery so NO jQuery in here.

How does one go about getting coordinates of `touchstart`, `touchend` and `touchmove` when `e.preventDefault` is enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates are in the `e` that is, the event variable.

```
var x = e.targetTouches[0].pageX,
    y = e.targetTouches[0].pageY;
```

From: [Obtaining Ipad touchstart coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228800/obtaining-ipad-touchstart-coordinates)

Comment: I will try this immediatly!

Comment: Thank you, it surley did work, will vote you in 10 minutes when I can! :)